# View historical record of applications used on a PC

Tags: history, application-launch, events, statistics

I want to access the exact time at which I turned on/off a program on windows 10. How can I find such records?

e.g. "Word.exe is started at 09:10 and terminated at 12:03."

I cannot find this in the event log.

Comment: This is not something I every see or also not needed in the client work I do. You would need to enable Workstation Auditing   https://www.manageengine.com/products/active-directory-audit/help/getting-started/configure-audit-logon-workstation-auditing.html

Answer (score 1):

The information you want is not in the event log. If you truly need this information (not often used), you need to enable workstation auditing.   Please see the information about this below:

https://www.manageengine.com/products/active-directory-audit/help/getting-started/configure-audit-logon-workstation-auditing.html